# Sum of arithmetic sequence given conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

> Let $a,a+d,a+2d,\cdots ,a+(n-1)d$ be an arithmetic sequence. If the sum of the first, third, fifth, and so on up to the last term is $320$, and the sum of the first, fourth, seventh, and so on up to the last term is $224$, then what is the sum of the entire sequence?

My attempt was to write the two equations that was given:
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor a+2\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor d=320$$
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor a+3\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor d=224$$

The expression we want to find the value of is
$$na+nd\frac{n-1}{2}$$

From there I'm stuck. You can't solve the system of two equations above, since there are three variables, so you have to somehow operate between them to reach the third equation. Any suggestions?

I remember seeing this problem somewhere, but I forgot where. If there are any mistakes in the problem, then swtich the "$320$" and the "$224$" in the equations above.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the implication of "up to the last term" is that $a+(n-1)d$ is in both sequences.

Comment: Really? Does that produce any results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progressions end at the same point, and we have $$a+(a+d)+ \dots + (a+6rd)= (6r+1)\frac {2a+6rd}2=(6r+1)(a+3rd)$$

$$a+(a+2d)+ \dots + (a+6rd)=(3r+1)(a+3rd)$$

$$a+(a+3d) + \dots +(a+6rd)=(2r+1)(a+3rd)$$

Note that the average of each progression is the same, but the number of terms differs.

Now note also that $6r+1=4\cdot (3r+1) - 3\cdot (2r+1)$

Answer (score 1):

We are looking at two new sequences here, both with the same term $a$. Since "the last term" is the same, $n$ must be divisible by $6$ (by both $2$ and $3$).

However, the first new sequence has common difference $2d$ and $\frac{n}2$ terms, and the second new sequence has common difference $3d$ and $\frac{n}3$ terms.

Just set $n=6k$ and use the usual sum-of-sequence formulas for $(3k,a,2d)$ and $(2k,a,3d)$. (Those triplets have number-of-terms, first-term, and common-difference.) You get two equations in three unknowns, but you can solve for two in terms of the third.

When you use those expressions in the formula for the sum of the original sequence, cancellation will occur and you get a clear answer.